# MATLAB: Hybrid method of using different ode solvers?

Tags: matlab

For one simulation process, is it possible to use Ode 45/23 for non-stiff region while use ode 15s for stiff region?

Let's say I start off with a stiff start so I use Ode 15s at first because it is faster. But at later times, the solution is mostly steady and involve only small changes, so I intend to use Ode 45 for later region because it is more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Suppose you know that the stiff region is from `t = 0` to `t = t1` and the non-stiff region is from `t = t1` to `t = tf`. Then, run `ode15s` on `tspan = [0,t1]` and then use these solutions as initial conditions for the `ode45` solver that runs on `tspan = [t1,tf]`.